# Correct use of or and nor

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct use of *nor* and *or* in the following sentence?

- *We pursued careers that we sought after and achieved,*
  *and entered others that we never expected **or** thought possible.*

Is it “or” or is it “nor”.  I say "or" is the correct grammar since "neither" is not used in the sentence.  Would appreciate your answer.

Comment: _Nor_ is a contraction of _not or_ and is often used as a correlative conjunction with _neither_ (a contraction of _not either_). The sentence you ask about is grammatical, and so is _... entered others that we **neither** expected **nor** thought possible._

Comment: This is beyond my pay grade, but I think it's because *never* (like *neither*) is a [negative polarity item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), that it's at the very least "correct" (though not *required*) to use ***nor*** as a conjunction in such contexts.

Comment: So, the way I originally wrote the sentence is grammatically correct using "or"?

Answer (score 1):

> We pursued careers that we sought after and achieved, and entered
>   others that we never expected **nor** thought possible

That is correct, however whilst beautifully put, it is a very formal and literary way of putting it, so unless it is for that specific purpose (to be formal and literary) I would say something a little les constructed and well put, maybe along the lines of:

> ... that we that we didn't expect or think possible

For spoken English, or fairly informal correspondance